# What's the difference bewteen '&> word' and '> word 2>&1' in the presence of multios in zsh?

Tags: zsh, io-redirection

As the [manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Opening-file-descriptors-using-parameters) said:

> Note that this does not have the same effect as ‘`> word 2>&1`’ in the presence of multios (see the section below).

But I don't figure out the difference between the two after reading the multios section. Could someone give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem will be that each instance of `2>&1` will cause stderr to redirected all over again to each redirection of stdout that was already done. See this example in [the multios section](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios):

> However, consider:
>
> ```
> date >output >&1
> ```
>
> As redirections are evaluated in order, when the `>&1` is encountered
> the standard output is set to the file output and another copy of the
> output is therefore sent to that file. This is unlikely to be what is
> intended.

And an example to illustrate the specific problem:

```
% (echo foo; echo bar >&2) &> baz &> baz2
% head baz baz2
==> baz <==
foo
bar

==> baz2 <==
foo
bar
```

Here, each line shows up once in each file, as is presumably intended by these redirections.

However, substituting in the `> word 2>&1` form directly for `&> word`:

```
% (echo foo; echo bar >&2) > baz 2>&1 > baz2 2>&1
% head baz baz2
==> baz <==
foo
bar
bar

==> baz2 <==
foo
bar
```

Note the extra copy of stderr send to the first file.

So the equivalent of `&> word1 &> word2 &> word3 ...` is actually just `> word1 > word2 > word3 ... 2>&1`.